# Disk partition windows installer

Tags: installation, windows, partitioning

I'm asking because I downloaded the windows installer version, when i open the installer, a window with everything is open and at the bottom say "install" but at middle sais "size instalation" and the max is 30Gb, that will be my ubuntu part in my pc? or after reboot it will say "selec your partition size"? what do you recommend me? its my first time, so its better if I download common installer and try with a CD?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first option is correct. The Wubi (Windows Ubuntu Installer) will install Ubuntu inside your Windows Hard drive's space. For example, if you selected 30GB, then Wubi will create a partition inside your Windows' hard drive.

For the best performance of course you should download the ISO, burn it on a CD and install it. However, Wubi is also a good option if you want to keep Windows and Ubuntu at the same time.